# How to check date between two datetimepickers?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim timeFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
Dim fromdate = SurrenderListForm.FromDatePicker.Value
Dim todate = SurrenderListForm.ToDatePicker.Value

MsgBox(fromdate.ToString(timeFormat))
MsgBox(todate.ToString(timeFormat))

SqlCon.Open()
SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM profile_tbl Where date_surrendered >= '" & fromdate.ToString(timeFormat) & "' AND 
                                date_surrendered < '" & todate.ToString(timeFormat) & "'", SqlCon)
SqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand)
SqlDataset = New DataSet

SqlAdapter.Fill(SqlDataset)
SqlCon.Close()
```

Comment: Hey @Noe welcome onboard. First of all you need to add some explanation on this what is your issue. Is your main issue that your  SqlCommand doesnt return desired data. The main issue is in sql table which may differ from your desired date format. Please add some text to your code

Comment: I have two datetimepicker sir, the problem is I need to select the data that the datesurrender is between of the two dates

Comment: Please edit your question to describe to us what result you expect and what result you get.

Comment: @NoeFabellon you can use modified query as 
`SELECT * FROM profile_tbl Where date_surrendered between '" & Format(SurrenderListForm.FromDatePicker.Value,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') & "' AND '" & Format(SurrenderListForm.ToDatePicker.Value,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') "'"`  note: Writing without editor

Answer (score 0):

Just try modifying you Query to something like this

```
SELECT * FROM profile_tbl Where date_surrendered 
        BETWEEN 
            '" & fromdate.ToString(timeFormat) & "' 
        AND 
            '" & todate.ToString(timeFormat) & "'
```

Here some additional help [@ W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_between.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the dates are being treated as strings. This often leads to code not working. Also, putting parameters in as strings in the SQL is the wrong way of doing it: the values need to be added as SQL parameters. Fortunately, it is easy to do it the right way:

```
Dim fromdate = SurrenderListForm.FromDatePicker.Value
Dim todate = SurrenderListForm.ToDatePicker.Value

fromdate = fromdate - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fromdate.Millisecond)
todate = todate - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(todate.Millisecond)

Dim connStr = "connection string goes here"
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM profile_tbl Where date_surrendered >= @FromDate AND date_surrendered < @ToDate"

Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
    Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@FromDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = fromdate})
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@ToDate", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = todate})

        Dim SqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
        SqlDataset = New DataSet

        SqlAdapter.Fill(SqlDataset)

    End Using
End Using
```

I assumed from the `timeFormat` variable that you didn't want any milliseconds involved.

The [`Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.7.2) method will open and close the connection for itself.

The [`Using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) construction makes sure that Dispose is called so that unmanaged resources are properly released.

Comment: I tried it sir, still not working, the data type of the date_surrendered in sql server is datetime

Comment: @NoeFabellon You are going to have to tell us what is not working. What results do you expect, and what results do you get?